# STAsText() Limitations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert geo data to polygon using STAsText() in SQL. 
My geo data looks like (I cannot paste full data because of body size limitations);

> 0xE610000001043110000088C5866B457144402016CCB0DD173D40F03A9FDF4571444050FA6624DD173D4080D79E6C46714440D06E7788DC173D404857EACF4671444030E5A8EADA173D40708AF0C246714440A054B2EFC7173D403897CA1D3D714440004DC320C6173D40E88C497E3C.....

Result is;

> POLYGON ((29.093226480317867 40.884931031042527, 29.093218112126408
>   40.884944870709546, 29.093208817633069 40.8849616790385, 29.093184152826495 40.884973515915192, 29.093160254242605 40.884971969081448, 29.093138579681977 40.884966799778056, 29.093116472547194 40.884953963754583, 29.093098521180025 40.884939883968741, 29.093084836196567 40.8849273699023, 29.093070224011683 40.884915351362736, 29.093045451286685 40.884917335266778, 29.093019076868984 40.8849201105748, 29.093019065600856 40.884920062628794, 29.093015848204345 40.884902864066021, 29.093034907375852 40.884885951034676, 29.09305525934451 40.884875936726019, 29.0930838274067 40.88486724587267, 29.093077411570675 40.884850217188955, 29.093056165809458 40.884833965415339, 29.093036923015575 40.884821392893116, 29.09300016232794 40.884829750292852, 29.092981070620169 40.88482338758962, 29.092981060225441 40.884823346405483, 29.092982130071903 40.884804377946693, 29.092973755446451 40.884787814659944, 29.092969614030721 40.884765353301134, 29.092966116352841 40.884748083968475, 29.092948528651789 40.884731053295809, 29.092923728047879....

Only 65535 byte is converted. I am looking for a way to convert complete polygon. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Are you copying the result out of Management Studio? If so, there's a setting in SSMS itself that limits the size of text returned. The default is 64K, which is what is getting returned to you.